# How to reference create_app from different sub-domain?

Tags: python, flask

The relevant part of my app structure looks like the following:

```
hp/
|
|---app/
     |---admin/
     |---auth/
     |---errors/
     |---main/
     |---__init__.py
     |---email.py
     |---models.py
     |---search.py
|---config.py
|---quiz.py
```

I want to create a `scripts/` domain in either `hp/` or `app/`. In those scripts I need to be able to reference config values. I'm using dotenv to do that. In order to use dotenv, I need `app` to be available so that I can call `app.config['CONFIG_NAME']`.

Here's more or less what I'm trying to do:

```py
import requests
from app import app

access_key = app.config['ACCESS_KEY']
secret_key = app.config['SECRET_KEY']

data = requests.get(f'https://api.foo.com/search?client_id={access_key}&page=1&query=foo').json()
```

If I try `from app import app`, as I have above, I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'` error. If I try `from .. import app` I get a `ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package` error.

Any guidance/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should post some of the actual python code, alongside your directory listing.

Comment: @v25 I added a bit of code to show the foundation of what I'm trying to do. Hopefully it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by changing the sys.path.

I added the following:

```py
import sys
import os
import inspect
currentdir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
appdir = os.path.dirname(currentdir)
hpdir = os.path.dirname(appdir)
sys.path.insert(0, hpdir)
from app import create_app

app = create_app()
```

After that I was able to successfully call `app.config`